# File name with spaces is treated as multiple files

Tags: bash

When I perform a search with, for example:

`find . -iname "U2*.mp3"`

or

`ls *U2`

I obtain the output:

```
U2 With or Without You.mp3
U2 When the Streets have no name.mp3
...
```

If I try to play them with the command:

`smplayer $(!!)`

then, smplayer assumes the filenames are:

```
U2
With
or
Without
...
```

How can I deal with this, without changing the file names?

Comment: Also `$(!!)` doesn't do what you think it does.  I recommend using the `-exec` functionality of `find` such as: `find . -iname 'U2*.mp3' -exec smplayer {} \;`

Comment: @Jesse_b: "doesn't do what you think it does"? Were you reading my thoughts? What does it does, and what do I think it does? This command works, when file names have no spaces...

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname "U2*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 smplayer
```